# MySQL, fetching data and server load

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, database, load

I'm building a web application that sends and gets data from a **MySQL** database. When a change is made in the db I want the changes to be shown on the web page in as close as realtime as possible.

Now to my question. How often is too often to fetch data from **MySQL** with **AJAX**? If I write a script that automatically checks for updates in the table every 5 seconds, isn't that going to increase the server load dramatically from my current 10-minute interval? How much can a server handle and are there any side effects?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would say that polling is not a great way to do it. Ideally you want the server to signal to the client that an update is ready, then have the client perform an intelligent refresh.

Take look at [Quantum](https://www.websocket.org/quantum.html) which appears to do what you need.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I don't get much of that at all. I've just started out with db:s..

Answer (score 0):

I just found out about Firebase, I'll try to migrate my system to one of their databases instead since that makes things a lot less difficult.